# IE 11 Compatibility Issue, setting document mode to 9 by default after making changes also in meta tag

Tags: sharepoint-2010, internet-explorer-11, compatibility, ie11-developer-tools

I made changes in the master page of my SharePoint site. I have added a `meta` tag in my header like so:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8,9,10,11" />
```

and I've also  changed the doctype, but the emulation is still rendering in IE9 document mode.

Attached is the screenshot.
[image: screenshot]

Please let me know where I need to make changes. This site is using custom master page. I have updated it in the Custom as well as the V4 master page but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

1. Set the `content` attribute of the `<meta>` tag to `"IE=8"` instead of `"IE=8,9,10,11"`.
2. Make sure that the `<meta>` tag containing your IE rendering directive is the *first* `<meta>` tag in the header.
3. To prevent the F12 developer tools window from forcing the page into a particular document mode, close all instances of Internet Explorer, then start it up again and revisit the site without the F12 developer tools open. Open the F12 developer tools to check the page document mode only **after** the page has loaded.